# Monitoring X11/RandR display traffic sent from PC

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, xrandr, display, image-manipulation

I'm trying to optimise my display parameters and have run into something of a brick-wall as it doesn't seem that `xrandr` is able to modify the `RGB Broadcast` value on my system, or otherwise it does not function correctly with my current hardware and drivers (throws error message when attempted).

With this in mind, what I would like to be able to do is to find the X11/RandR source code and modify it so as to allow me to either enable full RGB, or to create some approximation which will improve the extremely washed out colours currently outputting to my SyncMaster 2333HD. To help achieve this I would also like to be able to create a setup that monitors various aspects of the information the laptop is outputting via the HDMI port.

Does anyone know where I would need to look to find this, or at least where to start looking? I'm thinking I will first need to find the appropriate code for X11/RandR in the Linux /Unix Kernel? Also, I'll eventually need it to work on my Ubuntu system, so any considerations I should bear in mind for this distribution, particularly with regard to display output in relation to what I will be attempting?